# The steps to extract the total number of same data and maximum range of age from a single dataframe using pandas in python environment

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe shown below

```
Age Cardio 
74    1
77    1 
45    0
56    0
72    1
71    1
70    1
```

From this dataframe, how can i find the maximum age of an individual from 'Age' column and total number of 1 in 'Cardio' column using pandas?

The output should be 77 from 'Age' column and 5 from 'Cardio' column

I have tried this earlier

```
df.['Age'].max()
```

but its not showing anything

Comment: `df.agg({'Age': 'max', 'Cardio': 'sum'})`

Comment: kindly post your expected output dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) for `Series`:

```
s = df.agg({'Age': 'max', 'Cardio': 'sum'})
print (s)
Age       77
Cardio     5
dtype: int64
```

If need scalars:

```
age, no_1 = df['Age'].max(), df['Cardio'].sum()
```

Or:

```
age, no_1 = s['Age'], s['Cardio']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) with a dictionary mapping the column names and the aggregation functions:

```
df.agg({'Age': 'max', 'Cardio': 'sum'})
```

output:

```
Age       77
Cardio     5
dtype: int64
```

##### update

Getting the number of 0s in Cardio:

```
(df.assign(Cardio_0=df['Cardio'].rsub(1))
   .agg({'Age': 'max', 'Cardio': 'sum', 'Cardio_0': 'sum'})
)
```

output:

```
Age         77
Cardio       5
Cardio_0     2
dtype: int64
```

Second approach

```
def nzero(s):
    return len(s)-sum(s)
df.agg({'Age': 'max', 'Cardio': ['sum', nzero]})
```

output:

```
        Age  Cardio
max    77.0     NaN
sum     NaN     5.0
nzero   NaN     2.0
```

or as `stack` Series:

```
df.agg({'Age': 'max', 'Cardio': ['sum', nzero]}).stack()
```

output:

```
max    Age       77.0
sum    Cardio     5.0
nzero  Cardio     2.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: What will be my approach if i want to know total number of 0 in 'Cardio' column?

Comment: @subornodas you can use `lambda x: len(x)-sum(x)` as aggregation function

Comment: Or use the alternative(s), there are many ways to do this ;)

Comment: okay, thanks a lot. It did worked

Comment: @subornodas so which one did you want? Can you update the question to make it clear for future readers?

Comment: I just wanted the first one. Okay i am doing it